# Zsh spaces in associative array key

Tags: arrays, whitespace, zsh, associative-array

I'm trying to use array slice as associative array parameter like this:

```
a=( a b c d )
typeset -A b
b=( "a b c" d )
echo $b[$a[1,-2]]
```

But this doesn't work, and neither do this:

```
echo $b["a b c"]
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: `echo $b[$a[1,-2]]` doesn't work? I'm getting `d` just fine on 5.0.8 and 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR `${b[a b c]}` works, as does `${b[$a[1,-2]]}`.

There seem to be two issues:

1. `zsh` doesn't perform quote removal on array keys. `${b[a b c]}` works, but `${b["a b c"]}` does not.
2. The shorthand `$b[a b c]` seems to only work for "simple" keys. I don't know if the spaces cause word splitting, resulting in separate words `${b[a`, `b`, and `c]`, but adding braces to "disambiguate" the syntax seems to be the solution.

Comment: by "doesn't work" i meant evaluates to nothing. splitting to  `${b[a`,`b` and `c]` would cause syntax error

Comment: That's true. I'm not sure *why* it doesn't work. I wonder if it's a bug in the parser.

Comment: Actually, you tried `${b["a b c"]}`, not `${b[a b c]}`. The key in a subscript is already treated as though it were double quoted, so your double quotes were treated as part of the key, rather than simply protecting the whitespace. `$b[a b c]` appears to be subject to word splitting, though, which *does* produce a "bad subscript" error.